# Screen broken of my laptop, start with an external monitor

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, multiple-monitors

My laptop (SAMSUNG RC 420)screen is broken and the replacement of my screen arrives in three weeks. I'd like to start the laptop with external monitor.  I want to know if there is a way to boot from the boot my laptop because I have dual boot and password I cannot access my laptop with an external monitor for this reason. Is there a way to start my laptop directly to an external monitor.

I removed my broken laptop screen expecting that the system will recognize the VGA monitor, it but did not work me.

Comment: Try holding Fn + F3 at the same time? could switch between your laptop LCD and external display? [Link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000801.htm).

Comment: I saw your keyboard layout - I think it is Fn+F4. Try that.

Comment: for see the dual boot I try with fn + f4, fn + f3 and fn + f6 not work .